# Обработка запуска\остановки таймера на одной кнопке

Tags: c#

Понимаю, что вопрос совершенно дурной. Но гугл ответа не знает, а че то не выспался и туплю.
Есть след код :

```
private void notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)             
{                 
    MessageBox.Show(timer1.Enabled.ToString());  
    if (notifyIcon1.Text == ("Stop"))  
    {  
        notifyIcon1.Icon = new Icon("appicon.ico");  
        notifyIcon1.Text = ("Start");  
        timer1.Start();                         
    }  
    else  
    {  
         notifyIcon1.Icon = new Icon("stop.ico");  
         notifyIcon1.Text = ("Stop");  
         timer1.Stop();                        
    }    
}
```

выводит false, true. то есть он понимает что таймер не запущен, запускает его и снова обрабатывает нажатие и отключает его. как выйти из этого дикого цикла или как то изящнее написать timer1.enabled= !timer1.enabled не предлагать не работает. как вариант на 7ке работал такой код:

```
      switch (timer1.Enabled)  
      {  
          case true:  
          {  
              notifyIcon1.Icon = new Icon("stop.ico");  
              notifyIcon1.Text = ("Stop");  
              timer1.Stop();  
              Form1.ActiveForm.Focus();  
              break;
          }  
          case false:  
          {  
              notifyIcon1.Icon = new Icon("appicon.ico");  
              notifyIcon1.Text = ("Start");  
              timer1.Start();  
              Form1.ActiveForm.Focus();  
              break;
```

}
но из за  Form1.ActiveForm.Focus(); (форма у меня свернута, работа идет по двойному нажатию на иконку в трее, ) в ХР выпадает ошибка object reference not set to an instance

Comment: ой сам разобрался. проблема была в двойном определении this.notifyIcon1.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseEventHandler(notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick);
я его определил и еще отладчик свой код засунул. вот и два раз вызывалось. так что код вполне рабочий

Comment: ой убожество то какое ограничение на длину комента

Comment: private void notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{if (notifyIcon1.Text == ("Stop"))
                   {
                       notifyIcon1.Icon = new Icon("appicon.ico");
                       notifyIcon1.Text = ("Start");
                      timer1.Start();
                       return;
                   }
                   else{
                       notifyIcon1.Icon = new Icon("stop.ico");
                       notifyIcon1.Text = ("Stop");
                       timer1.Stop();
                       return;
                   }выаааааааааааааааааааааа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вообще все решается элементарной проверкой свойства Enabled (да-да, это работает, вы тут очевидно допустили старую как мир ошибку - перепутали равенство и присваивание). Выглядеть это будет так:

```
    private void notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(timer1.Enabled.ToString());

        if (timer1.Enabled)
        {
            notifyIcon1.Icon = new Icon("stop.ico");
            notifyIcon1.Text = ("Stop");
            timer1.Stop();
        }
        else
        {
            notifyIcon1.Icon = new Icon("appicon.ico");
            notifyIcon1.Text = ("Start");
            timer1.Start();
        }
    }
```

Впрочем, определенного внимания заслуживает и сам ваш код. Никогда не нужно проверять булевские значения таким ужасным способом, как вы это делаете:

```
notifyIcon1.Text == ("Stop")
```

Это весьма типичный пример [индусского кода](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.80.D1.8B_.D0.B8.D0.BD.D0.B4.D1.83.D1.81.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.BE_.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B0). Впрочем, switch для bool - это тоже удачный пример плодов деятельности индусского программиста, так тоже писать не стоит. Ну и логика в обработчиках - это тоже нехорошо

Comment: Отличный код, что Вы в самом деле

Comment: @Veikedo это ведь ирония?

Comment: ну конечно поглумился, че уж тут. да, признаю, что код наверно грубоват и можно эстетичнее писать. просто пишу месяц, пока всех тонкостей не знаю. так сказать микроскопом гвозди забиваю( ну это я про кейс, свитч ("но работало же!!!")). но этот ваш if (timer1.Enabled) во первых не работает. а во вторых когда все идеи закончились я сделал как предлагает мсдн - то есть в Майкрософт тоже индусы сидят? (хоть и каламбур, ведь сча директор индус, хех). но вот пруф  http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/3tszykws%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: >ну это я про кейс, свитч ("но работало же!!!"))

это однако же не означает, что так нужно писать. Как вы сами верно заметили - забивание гвозде микроскопом

>но этот ваш if (timer1.Enabled) во первых не работает

очень даже работает - этот код был мной написан тут после отладки в студии. Мне нет смысла вам врать. Если у вас что-то не работает, то показывайте код. 146%, что у вас там ошибка (либо мы вообще с вами говорим о разных вещах)

Comment: >в Майкрософт тоже индусы сидят?

Несмотря на то, что он размещен на MSDN, с точки зрения здравого смысла это говнокод. Однако тут нужно помнить, что это не более, чем учебный пример, а в целях обучения авторы часто идут на сознательное упрощение материала, чтобы избежать многословности и трудностей в понимании кода. Авторы таких учебных примеров преследуют только цель показать пример работы с тем или иным классом библиотеки, а не написать корректный и хороший код (это не упрек в их адрес, а скорее совет не забывать, что код с MSDN не всегда стоит брать и целиком копировать к себе)

Comment: Ошибался.  if (timer1.Enabled)  работает вполне корректно